# Python libraries not available in rstudio

Tags: python, r, numpy, rstudio

I'm new to using R and Rmarkdown, and I am trying to use numpy in a python chunk of an .rmd file. I tried to install numpy but its not available to use. I've set my python environment in R to the system environment but I'm still not able to use it.

This is my code:

```
py_install('numpy') 
reticulate::py_module_available('numpy')
```

and this is the message I get when I run it:

```
> py_install('numpy')
+ "C:/Users/MID80/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/condabin/conda.bat" "install" "--yes" "--name" "r-reticulate" "-c" "conda-forge" "numpy"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.

> reticulate::py_module_available('numpy')
[1] FALSE
```

I do have system wide python setup from microsoft store, and I'm using miniconda.

```
> reticulate::conda_list()
          name                                                  python
1         base                     C:\\Users\\MID80\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda/python.exe
2 r-reticulate C:\\Users\\MID80\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\r-reticulate/python.exe
> reticulate::py_discover_config()
python:         C:/Users/MID80/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/MID80/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python311.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/MID80/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311
version:        3.11.5 (tags/v3.11.5:cce6ba9, Aug 24 2023, 14:38:34) [MSC v.1936 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python() function
> reticulate::py_available(initialize = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
> env.profile(env)
Error: object 'env' not found
> env_ <- Sys.getenv()
> env_[grep("PY", names(env_), ignore.case = TRUE)]
PYTHONIOENCODING           utf-8
RETICULATE_PYTHON_FALLBACK
                           C:/Users/MID80/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe
```

Comment: Can you describe your setup? Do you have a system-wide Pyhton installation,  is  it from python.org, Microsoft store or from some other source? Are you using Anaconda / miniconda? Do you have any python-related environment variables set in your R session? You can check with something like `env_ <- Sys.getenv(); env_[grep("PY", names(env_), ignore.case = TRUE)]`  .  Are you using RStudio projects? What do you get for `reticulate::conda_list()`, `reticulate::py_discover_config()`, `reticulate::py_available(initialize = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @margusl I added results of those to original post. Thanks!